# How to check if it is draw (java game)

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm new to Java and I need some help with 2D arrays.

In short, it's a 4x4 grid where each player decides which position to obtain via input.

Player1 uses "1", player2 uses "2". The winner is the person who occupies 2x2.
E.g.

```
1 2 0 0
0 1 1 2
2 1 1 2
2 0 0 0
```

Player 1 wins in this case. I have no problem deciding who of the two wins, but I can't implement a correct draw check. E.g

```
1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2
```

It's a draw game because no player obtained 2x2 in the grid. However, I have no idea how to detect that without breaking something else. :(

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to detect a winner there shouldn't be a problem detecting if the game ended in a draw:

1. look for a winner
2. no winner found? It's a draw.

Comment: @BlagovestBalchev Yes, no matter what way you check for a winner you should be able to communicate that no winner was found. A very simple solution would be to add a flag `found_winner` (initialized to false) which is set to `true` upon finding a winner in your nested loop. If `found_winner` is false after the loop, it was a draw.

Comment: The problem is that check is done after each player's turn. If the loop doesn't find a winner, it says draw. :( 
Either that or I did something wrong.

Comment: You should only print/display/say "draw" when the whole board is full, ie. every slot has been taken by either player #1 or player #2.

Comment: How can I check if it's full? 0 should be ignored because it means there is still a position that is not occupied.

Comment: @BlagovestBalchev One of the easiest ways is to count the number of `0` on the board, if you couldn't find any - the board is full.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the array and search for consecutive occurrence of 2 or 1.

If none exits, its a draw!

```
int board[][] = new int[4][4]; 
boolean drawFlag = true;

for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
 {
   for(int j=1; j<4; j++)
     {
        if(board[i][j-1] == board[i][j])
           drawFlag = false;
      }
  }

  if(drawFlag == true)
     System.out.println("Its a draw!");
```

Comment: The above code is sadly far from correct. A question to point out one of it's flaws: what element will be read when `i = 0` and `j = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose , you're asking how to detect patterns of game state. I define 3 state of game, these are : draw (0) , win (1) and not-determined (2). While game is being played and win or lost condition is not certain ,then game state is not-determined. Your problem is completely involves generating algorithm of evaluation of game state. And it gets a little complex in detail. Whatever you asked, solution of the problem is the way in the code given below. If you need further explanation , feel free to feedback.

The solution consist of two operations. First operation scans matrix at given start coordinates for win condition. Second operation generates all start coordinates for first operation.

That is what mentioned as first operation and returns values as defined above :

```
int evaluateSection(int startPosX, int startPosY)
{
    int firstVal;
    boolean emptyExists = false;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 && j==0)
                firstVal = matrix[startPosX + i][startPosY + j];
            else if(firstVal == 0)
            {
                firstVal = matrix[startPosX + i][startPosY + j];
                emptyExists = true;
            }

            else if(matrix[startPosX + i][startPosY + j] !=0 && matrix[startPosX + i][startPosY + j] !=firstVal)
                return 0;
            else if(matrix[startPosX + i][startPosY + j] ==0)
                emptyExists = true;

        }

    }
    if(emptyExists==false)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;

}
```

Second operation scans all sections in gameplay area and uses first operation:

```
int result()
{
    int tmp,res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            tmp=evaluateSection(i,j);
            if(tmp==0 && res!=2)
                res=0;
            if(tmp==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(tmp==2)
            {
                res=2;
            }
        }
    return res;
}
```

As you see , it gets complicated. But algorithm is in this way. Have a try.

Comment: I guess , I provided detailed algorithm ... And couldn't understand the above response has got 3 upvotes although it's rough and not making much sense.